# XML, java , unicode

Tags: java, xml

In XML, if one character unicode is written as \ue123 in Java

how can a string of two characters be written ?

note I tried \u123\u123 but it didn't work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `\u123\u123` doesn't work because `\u` needs to be followed by *four* hex digits. But this should work fine:

```
String text = "\u0123\u0123";
```

Note that this is just the Java string literal side - it has nothing to do with XML. XML has different ways of escaping the characters it needs to, but if you use an appropriate encoding (e.g. UTF-8) you shouldn't need to escape non-ASCII characters.